# Returning array of pointer from function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I want to return an array of pointer from the `return_string function`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char **return_string(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int i = 0;
  char **val = return_string();

  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    printf("%s\t%d\n", val[i],val[i]);
  return 0;
}

char **return_string(void)
{
   char* val[] = {"foo", "bar", "something"};
   return val;
}
```

1.When compiled, I got a warning `function returning address of local variable`

2.When running, I just get garbage instead of the string I want.

Any idea why this happens and how do I return an `array of pointer` from `function`?

Comment: You cannot pass/return arrays from/to functions in C. And there is no array in your code.

Comment: And pay heed to warnings. That one is very specific already.

Comment: @Olaf "there is no array in your code" - `char* val[]` is of course an array.

Answer (score 1):

`val` is an automatic variable so it goes **out of scope** after `return_string` has returned. Therefore, modifying it through a pointer beyond function scope is **undefined behavior**.

You could:

1. Allocate the array on the free store:

   ```
   char **return_string(void)
   {
      char** val = malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);
      val[0] = "foo";
      val[1] = "bar";
      val[2] = "something";
      return val;
   }
   ```
2. Pass a pointer to the function and work on the pointer:

   ```
   void return_string(char** ptr);

   ...

   char* array[3];
   return_string(array);

   ...

   void return_string(char** ptr)
   {
       ptr[0] = "foo";
       ptr[1] = "bar";
       ptr[2] = "something";
   }
   ```

Comment: can you please explain what is `malloc(sizeof(char*) * 3);` mean?

Comment: @LunduHarianja What in specific: `malloc` or `sizeof(char*) * 3`? Or both? You can also search the Internet on both.

Comment: @LunduHarianja: May I recommend to consult a C book or a good tutorial?